# Excel - Repeat Cell Values In a Sequence

Tags: excel

All,

I have a list of values in a column that I need to repeat in a separate column four times, then repeat the next value four times, and so on. I can't think of a good way to do it. An example of what I need is below.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX() with some math.

Put this in B1 and copy down:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)+1)
```

As it is copied down the ROW(1:1), which resolves to 1, will change to ROW(2:2), which resolves to 2, and so forth.

The math takes care of the rest.

[image]